# PyContextProtocol example for pyo3?

Tags: rust, pyo3

In the `__enter__` method I want to return an object which is accessible in Rust and Python, so that Rust is able to update values in the object and Python can read the updated values.

I would like to have something like this:

```
#![feature(specialization)]

use std::thread;

use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::types::{PyType, PyAny, PyDict};
use pyo3::exceptions::ValueError;
use pyo3::PyContextProtocol;
use pyo3::wrap_pyfunction;

#[pyclass]
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Statistics {
    pub files: u32,
    pub errors: Vec<String>,
}

fn counter(
    root_path: &str,
    statistics: &mut Statistics,
) {
    statistics.files += 1;
    statistics.errors.push(String::from("Foo"));
}

#[pyfunction]
pub fn count(
    py: Python,
    root_path: &str,
) -> PyResult<PyObject> {
    let mut statistics = Statistics { 
        files: 0,
        errors: Vec::new(),
    };

    let rc: std::result::Result<(), std::io::Error> = py.allow_threads(|| {
        counter(root_path, &mut statistics);
        Ok(())
    });
    let pyresult = PyDict::new(py);
    match rc {
        Err(e) => { pyresult.set_item("error", e.to_string()).unwrap();
                    return Ok(pyresult.into())
                  },
        _ => ()
    }
    pyresult.set_item("files", statistics.files).unwrap();
    pyresult.set_item("errors", statistics.errors).unwrap();
    Ok(pyresult.into())
}

#[pyclass]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Count {
    root_path: String,
    exit_called: bool,
    thr: Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>,
    statistics: Statistics,
}

#[pymethods]
impl Count {
    #[new]
    fn __new__(
        obj: &PyRawObject,
        root_path: &str,
    ) {
        obj.init(Count {
            root_path: String::from(root_path),
            exit_called: false,
            thr: None,
            statistics: Statistics { 
                files: 0,
                errors: Vec::new(),
            },
        });
    }

    #[getter]
    fn statistics(&self) -> PyResult<Statistics> {
       Ok(Statistics { files: self.statistics.files,
                       errors: self.statistics.errors.to_vec(), })
    }
}

#[pyproto]
impl<'p> PyContextProtocol<'p> for Count {
    fn __enter__(&mut self) -> PyResult<Py<Count>> {
        let gil = GILGuard::acquire();
        self.thr = Some(thread::spawn(|| {
            counter(self.root_path.as_ref(), &mut self.statistics)
        }));
        Ok(PyRefMut::new(gil.python(), *self).unwrap().into())
    }

    fn __exit__(
        &mut self,
        ty: Option<&'p PyType>,
        _value: Option<&'p PyAny>,
        _traceback: Option<&'p PyAny>,
    ) -> PyResult<bool> {
        self.thr.unwrap().join();
        let gil = GILGuard::acquire();
        self.exit_called = true;
        if ty == Some(gil.python().get_type::<ValueError>()) {
            Ok(true)
        } else {
            Ok(false)
        }
    }
}

#[pymodule(count)]
fn init(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_class::<Count>()?;
    m.add_wrapped(wrap_pyfunction!(count))?;
    Ok(())
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
error[E0477]: the type `[closure@src/lib.rs:90:39: 92:10 self:&mut &'p mut Count]` does not fulfill the required lifetime
  --> src/lib.rs:90:25
   |
90 |         self.thr = Some(thread::spawn(|| {
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: type must satisfy the static lifetime
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important.

Comment: Playground is missing pyo3 crate. So i've created a minimal example here: https://github.com/brmmm3/scandir-rs/tree/master/context.
The error message can be found in error.txt.
The thread counter is normally a longer running thread, while in Python it is possible to get current statistics while the thread is running.

Comment: [To make Stack Overflow a useful resource for future visitors beyond the context of your repository](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380194/155423), please [edit] your question to add a [MRE] in the question itself, in addition to the link to your repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution. The use of a guarded reference does the trick:

```
#![feature(specialization)]

use std::{thread, time};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

extern crate crossbeam_channel as channel;
use channel::{Sender, Receiver, TryRecvError};

use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::types::{PyType, PyAny};
use pyo3::exceptions::ValueError;
use pyo3::PyContextProtocol;

#[pyclass]
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Statistics {
    pub files: u32,
    pub errors: Vec<String>,
}

pub fn counter(
    statistics: Arc<Mutex<Statistics>>,
    cancel: &Receiver<()>,
) {
    for _ in 1..15 {
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(100));
        {
            let mut s = statistics.lock().unwrap();
            s.files += 1;
        }
        match cancel.try_recv() {
            Ok(_) | Err(TryRecvError::Disconnected) => {
                println!("Terminating.");
                break;
            }
            Err(TryRecvError::Empty) => {}
        }
    }
    {
        let mut s = statistics.lock().unwrap();
        s.errors.push(String::from("Foo"));
    }
}

#[pyclass]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Count {
    exit_called: bool,
    statistics: Arc<Mutex<Statistics>>,
    thr: Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>,
    cancel: Option<Sender<()>>,
}

#[pymethods]
impl Count {
    #[new]
    fn __new__(obj: &PyRawObject) {
        obj.init(Count {
            exit_called: false,
            statistics: Arc::new(Mutex::new(Statistics {
                files: 0,
                errors: Vec::new(),
            })),
            thr: None,
            cancel: None,
        });
    }

    #[getter]
    fn statistics(&self) -> PyResult<u32> {
        let s = Arc::clone(&self.statistics).lock().unwrap().files;
        Ok(s)
     }
}

#[pyproto]
impl<'p> PyContextProtocol<'p> for Count {
    fn __enter__(&'p mut self) -> PyResult<()> {
        let statistics = self.statistics.clone();
        let (sender, receiver) = channel::bounded(1);
        self.cancel = Some(sender);
        self.thr = Some(thread::spawn(move || {
            counter(statistics, &receiver)
        }));
        Ok(())
    }

    fn __exit__(
        &mut self,
        ty: Option<&'p PyType>,
        _value: Option<&'p PyAny>,
        _traceback: Option<&'p PyAny>,
    ) -> PyResult<bool> {
        let _ = self.cancel.as_ref().unwrap().send(());
        self.thr.take().map(thread::JoinHandle::join);
        let gil = GILGuard::acquire();
        self.exit_called = true;
        if ty == Some(gil.python().get_type::<ValueError>()) {
            Ok(true)
        } else {
            Ok(false)
        }
    }
}

#[pyproto]
impl pyo3::class::PyObjectProtocol for Count {
    fn __str__(&self) -> PyResult<String> {
        Ok(format!("{:?}", self))
    }
}

#[pymodule(count)]
fn init(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_class::<Count>()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Now I can run the following code:

```
import time

import count

c = count.Count()

with c:
    for _ in range(5):
        print(c.statistics)
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

As the example shows thread cancelling also works, although a maybe nicer solution is using the crate `thread_control`.